# What's causes "403 cannotDownloadFile : This file cannot be downloaded by the user."?

Tags: google-drive-api

Downloading a file via a [`GET`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) request sometimes results in this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "cannotDownloadFile",
        "message": "This file cannot be downloaded by the user."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "This file cannot be downloaded by the user."
  }
}
```

I'm still identifying what type/s of files results in this error. I've tried looking for the cause in the [Drive API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_usage_limit_exceeded), but it seems that it isn't mentioned anywhere.

Anyone know what causes this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed this in different accounts? And for different files? Are you sure you have access to the file you want to download?

Comment: @iamblichus Yes, this issue happened for different accounts. As for the files, it happened for different files as well. I was able to replicate the issue for shared files by disabling downloads for the file (using the owner's account) -- the sharee was unable to download it and got the said error.

Though one thing I've noticed, some of the files are PDFs which might have been possibly flagged for copyright.

Comment: Well, that's most probably what's going on: files are protected from downloading.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've observed so far, this happens for files where the option "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers." is set.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en